# HTTP response containing HTML login form response (paypal express style)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I work for a payment platform and we are considering adding "PayPal express checkout"-style functionality to our API (specifically on login)

So their site will make a request to our API which we will return an HTML form (which they would open in a modal presumably) that allows them to enter their username and password securely which will return the JWT needed to perform subsequent actions on our API.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this? Maybe some technologies I can look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not send HTML as a response to someone else render in their site, this would be completely insecure since the third party site would be able to check the info filled in the form.
(I don't know if you were thinking this way, but just in case you were...)

The easier way to do this is implementing a script to append in the third party site, that when someone checks out you make an API call to your payment gateway, then your server send a URL for checking out as a response. So your script in the third party website should open a pop-up (like the one in PayPal express checkout) to your Gateway's website to process the checkout. At the same time, your script in the third party website need to communicate to your gateway's server through a websocket to keep listening for the result of the transaction, whether success of failure, to callback this result in the third party website using JS.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is very helpful. Will be going in this direction this week